# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb' Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

I'm learning the Spring Framework, and I'm doing the HelloWeb tutorial on tutorialspoint, and I can't get it working. I'm using Spring MVC 4.0, and I'm deploying my app from Netbeans 8.0 to a Glassfish Server.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm

I looked for similar problems here on this site and on other sites as well, but the suggested solutions didn't work for me. I would really appreciate some help, because I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic here.

Here are my relevant files:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

<bean id="viewResolver"  class=
"org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

Comment: What is the context path of the application, and what is the URL in the browser address bar?

Comment: @JBNizet The context path of the application is /HelloWeb and the URL is http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/

Comment: what happens when you try it out?

Comment: The GlassFish server threw a 404 page error and the Netbeans console showed the error in the title. But it is solved now, and the answer below is the right one. I just can't figure out why does it work now, when it didn't previously :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a single controller in your app, mapped to `/hello` (that's what `@RequestMapping("/hello")` means). The URL for that controller is thus `http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello`.

Comment: Ok...so I feel kinda embarrassed, because this solution is in one of the related threads, and when I tried that it didn't work. It didn't recognize /HelloWeb/hello either. Now it works though, so thanks. I wonder if Firefox cache kept serving me the GlassFish 404 page.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible that the port was used so that's why it couldn't find it before. I know Skype uses 8080, but shouldn't that block glassfish entirely? I'm grasping at straws here, because I've only worked with apache and php until now, my web knowledge is limited with other techs.

Comment: Glassfish would have given you an error if its port was not available. And Skype wouldn't have thrown a SpringMVC exception. I doubt Firefox would cache 404 pages. When in doubt, use the reload button while pressing the Shift key: that forces the browser to reload without checking the cache.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind although I do use ctrl-shift R instead of F5, so I really don't know. But thanks anyway...I will try to be more careful next time. Best regards!

Comment: im sorry, i still didnt get it. Im facing the same problem. Act, what should I do?

Comment: @Chi The problem was that I didn't enter the correct URL to access the page. The correct URL should contain both the application's context path and the RequestMapping of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this work fine for you.
I got same error but i resolved to update **HelloWeb-servlet.xml** 
here you can put this code in **HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
```